# HTML 5 Local Database Row Count

Tags: database, html, local

HTML local database how do I make line substitution?

EX

```
mydb.transaction(function (t) {
            t.executeSql("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM offline", outputCars);    
         alert(t);
     });
```

but it's not working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try it like

```
mydb.transaction(function (t) {
    t.executeSql("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM offline", [], function (tx, results) {
        alert(results.rows[0].count});
     }
 });
```